# Fix keyboard problem on ubuntu

Tags: keyboard

When I type @ or & on my keyboard 0 is typed randomly. Even just pressing shift key does that. How can I fix that?

My Ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: Try opening a terminal and type `stty sane` or try changing **Settings / Language and Region ** and try a different keyboard (not too different).

Comment: @darth_epoxy It's not a problem with keyboard layout. On startup I see something like "^[22" is repeated so many times.

Comment: @heynnema what do you think?